# Why do I keep ending up with blank data in this multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I copied/modified a class using ThreadPoolExector, and a function to do submit called add_task thereby doing submit of a function and args to the pool, but when there are times when the function it's doing from the pool has blank data.  I suspect this is because I am clearing the list after submitting it, but I don't know how to fix it. Sending a function call doesn't copy the variable, right? It just passes a reference? So if in between the time that the function is submitted and the time the thread gets picked up dictlist.clear() is called, the thread no longer has a value to submit to POST? Is that a race condition? How do I fix this? I was under the impression that ThreadPoolExecution (and Queue, since I tried that also) did locking themselves, but perhaps I'm missing something major here.

This is the code that calls the class function:

```
with open(xmfp + "pythoncsvSector.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as sectorcsv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(sectorcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) # fieldnames parameter skipped so it knows first row is headers
    for row in reader:
        dictlist.append(row)
        counter += 1
        if counter == 100:
            pool.add_task(submitToSite, dictlist, "Sector")
            dictlist.clear()
            counter = 0
```

and this is the class:

```
class ThreadExecutor:
    def __init__(self, max_workers):
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers)

    def add_task(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            future = self.executor.submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            return future
```

The function that I'm calling does a POST request and writes the response text and status code to a file.

Here's the code in full: https://pastebin.com/Qu6cYSnE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are shared between threads. In this case you can submit a copy of the list instead to the worker thread if you are going to mutate the original list:

```
pool.add_task(submitToSite, dictlist[:], "Sector")
```

or you can assign to `dictlist` a new list instead of clearing it in-place with `dictlist.clear()`:

```
dictlist = []
```

Comment: THANK YOU * 10000  I tried it with dictlist.copy() and it just gave me an error and I just thought you couldn't do it with a copy somehow.